# React With Keycloak Redirect Loop

Tags: reactjs, keycloak

I am both react and keycloak novice and I am trying to learn how both integrate together.
I try using as few libraries as possible while learning to make sure I understand all the core concepts properly - so no Keycloak wrapper, no redux state and so on.

My problem is that I end up with an infinite loop after keycloak authentication since I want to set the current user in the component state.

I understand why the loop happens - setting the state will trigger the re-render of my component in which I do the authentication but I have no idea what is the best way to fix it.

```
export const App = function () {
    const [user, setUser] = useState('unknown');

    const keycloak = new Keycloak();
    keycloak.init({
        onLoad: 'login-required'
    }).then(function (authenticated) {
        //setUser(keycloak.tokenParsed.preferred_username); // <-- uncommenting this line does a redirect loop
        alert(authenticated ? 'authenticated' : 'not authenticated');
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log('Failed to initialize keycloak', e);
    });

    return (
        <div>
            Hello {user}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Keycloak config

```
{
  "realm": "master",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/",
  "url": "http://localhost:8080/",
  "resource": "bankerise",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "public-client": true
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing it in wrong way! The problem with your code is that you are setting state inside the component body alone without wrapping it inside of anything. So, this will be executed every time the component re-renders. The setting of state triggers the re-render as well.

So basically, when you are setting state, react re-renders the page and upone hitting the same line i.e., setting the state line, react trigger re-renders again. You got the point right. So the loop.

So here is you copy-pasta code

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export const App = function () {
  const [user, setUser] = useState('unknown');

  useEffect(() => {
    const keycloak = new Keycloak();
    keycloak
      .init({
        onLoad: 'login-required',
      })
      .then(function (authenticated) {
        setUser(keycloak.tokenParsed.preferred_username); // <-- uncommenting this line does a redirect loop
        alert(authenticated ? 'authenticated' : 'not authenticated');
      })
      .catch(function (e) {
        console.log('Failed to initialize keycloak', e);
      });
  }, []);

  return <div>Hello {user}</div>;
};
```